# Ошибка при записи в БД (GlassFish 4.1.1, JPA, EclipseLink, Spring MVC)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, eclipselink

Есть такой класс, который сопоставлен таблице MS SQL:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dbo.Mans")
public class Mans implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    public Mans() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

### DAO:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class MansDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void add(Mans person) {
        /*ЗАПИСЬ В БД*/
        em.persist(person);            
    }

    public List<Mans> listPersons() {
        CriteriaQuery<Mans> criteriaQuery = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Mans.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Root<Mans> root = criteriaQuery.from(Mans.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(root);
        List<Mans> m = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        return m;
    }
}
```

### persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.mycompany_mavenWebTest2_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:app/tdb</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.mycompany.mawenwebtest2.models.Mans</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
    <properties>      
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Выборка происходит нормально. Но, при записи в БД пишет ошибку:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object:
>   com.mycompany.mawenwebtest2.models.Mans@71f0c6bf is not a known Entity
>   type

Использую GlassFish 4.1.1, JPA, EclipseLink и Spring MVC.

Вопрос: Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Поиск в интернете не помог.

Comment: А Ваш Entity зарегистрирован в persistence.xml?

Comment: Зарегистрирован и при вызове `persist()` EclipseLink запрос даже не формирует.

Comment: Я бы на Вашем месте, если проблема до сих пор не решилась, провел бы чистое тестирование, то есть взял бы реализацию JPA, взял Ваши классы и попробовал с ними поработать без GlassFish и Spring. Вот здесь я игрался с JPA, использовал свои классы, реализацию JPA и локальную базу H2DB. Посмотрите, может что найдете: [github](https://github.com/ezhov-da/java-ee-examples/tree/master/cdi-book-service/src)